# JavaScript - Check if an array has concurrent numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

If you had an array with 5 items, what would be the best way to check if those items are in order? Say 1-5 or 6-11?

**EDIT**

Knowing a loop will work, I'm wondering if there might be an alternative solution.

Comment: Iterate through the array comparing the current value to the previous, and if you find one that's not exactly 1 greater then the result is `false`, otherwise `true`.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Are you stuck on a particular point of your solution?

Comment: Also I think the word you're looking for is *consecutive* not *concurrent*.

Comment: No, I'm not stuck, knowing that a loop would work, but I expected there might be a more elegant solution that I was unaware of, or unable to find in my search. I should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: @JesseJamesRichard since this answer is closed and I can no longer submit an answer, I made a little gist for you – [gist: consecutive.js](https://gist.github.com/naomik/8ee9fd3e656e658f453e38f87b33aca4)

Answer (score 2):

Loop through, if the current is less than the previous return false.

```js
function consecutive(arr)
{
  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
     if(arr[i] < arr[i-1]) return false; 
  }
  return true;
  
}

console.log(consecutive([10,11,45,100]));
console.log(consecutive([10,3,11,35]));
```